# passing argument strings to execl in C++

Tags: c++

I need to pass the following string into the execl method

```
execl("/usr/bin/awk", "awk", "{print > \"merged.txt\"}", files.c_str() , (char*) 0);
```

I can imagin that this does NOT work. Since it is simply a different method signature. However, how can I ensure that the `files.c_str()` is evaluated?

In the `files` variable are the following arguments: `./tmp_file-10574.txt, ./tmp_file-10575.txt, ./tmp_file-10576.txt`

I basically wish to call call the method like this (replacing the files.c_str()):

```
execl("/usr/bin/awk", "awk", "{print > \"merged.txt\"}", ./tmp_file-10574.txt, ./tmp_file-10575.txt, ./tmp_file-10576.txt , (char*) 0);
```

This is awk's response: `awk: cannot open tmp_file-11180.txt tmp_file-11181.txt tmp_file-11182.txt (No such file or directory)`

Note, if the `files` variable consists of only one file e.g. `./tmp_file-10574.txt` it works all nicely.

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? [Of course, it would be better if you posted a complete example, that shows what you are concerned about/what is going wrong]

Comment: Because it works with one file. But not if many are in that variable. Any more ideas? I also tried to remove the commas in the string. No luck.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. You'll need to split the string in your code, so that it's one string per filename, and then pass all the strings to `execl` (or one of the other flavours of `exec`)

Comment: Alternatively, build a single string of all the command including argumetns, and use `system` to execute it.